# Delete or Remove Calendar Rule "Time Off Rule" through a plugin or simple console application in C# for CRM 2015

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have the following problem:

I need to delete or remove "Time Off Rule" from Calendar Rules of a particular calendar belonging to an "Equipment". This needs to be done so that the equipment is available for scheduling on Service Calendar.

Somehow I cannot understand how to do it.

I am able to retrieve the Calendar rule object which needs to be deleted but the next step eludes me.

Please be kind enough to let me know:

1. Can it be done through C#(SDK)
2. Any web resource or portion of code which does something similar.

The following code gives me the error

> The object you tried to delete is associated with another object and
>   cannot be deleted.

```
//equip is of Equipment type and is already initialized 
CrmEarlyBound.Calendar cal = (CrmEarlyBound.Calendar)svc.Retrieve("calendar", equip.CalendarId.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
Console.WriteLine("Got the user calendar");
List<CalendarRule> calendarRules = cal.CalendarRules.ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Got the calendar rules " +  cal.CalendarRules.ToList().Count);
foreach (CalendarRule cr in cal.CalendarRules)
{
   if (cr.Description == "Time Off Rule" && cr.StartTime.Value>=DateTime.Now)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(cr.StartTime);
       Calendar calI = (Calendar)svc.Retrieve(cr.InnerCalendarId.LogicalName, cr.InnerCalendarId.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
       //svc.Delete(cr.InnerCalendarId.LogicalName, cr.InnerCalendarId.Id);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Have to remove the `calendarrules` collection & update the `calendar` entity.

```
public static void ClearCalenderRules(IOrganizationService service, Guid bookableResourceId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    using (var context = new CrmServiceContext(service))
    {
        var bookableResource = context.BookableResourceSet.Where(b => b.Id == bookableResourceId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (bookableResource?.CalendarId != null)
        {

            Entity entity = service.Retrieve("calendar", bookableResource.CalendarId.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
            EntityCollection entityCollection = (EntityCollection)entity.Attributes["calendarrules"];

            int num = 0;
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            foreach (Entity current in entityCollection.Entities)
            {
                DateTime dateTime2 = Convert.ToDateTime(current["starttime"]);
                if (dateTime2 >= startDate && dateTime2 <= endDate)
                {
                    list.Add(num);
                }

                num++;
            }

            list.Sort();
            list.Reverse();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                entityCollection.Entities.Remove(entityCollection.Entities[list[i]]);
            }

            entity.Attributes["calendarrules"] = entityCollection;
            service.Update(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

[source](http://thusithasblog.blogspot.com/2017/02/deleting-calendar-rules-in-microsoft.html)